# List users that have most tokens

Tags: mysql

[image]

This is my `tokens_log` table. I want to list ten users that have most tokens.

So result should be like this:

```
*# Username    sumOfTokens*

#1  tolgay007     500

#2  hzrose        100

...
```

I tried following sql but didn't work.

```
SELECT * , SUM( token )
FROM `user_tokens_list`
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY SUM( token ) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

How can i achive this?

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  the column in group by instead of *

```
  SELECT username , SUM( token )
  FROM `user_tokens_list`
  WHERE  transaction ='sale' 
  GROUP BY username
  ORDER BY SUM( token ) DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

and use a proper where

or if you need  all the column you need  a join on subquery for username

```
  SELECT user_tokens_list.*, t.sum_token 
  FROM `user_tokens_list`
  INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT username , SUM( token ) sum_token
    FROM `user_tokens_list`
    transaction ='sale' 
    GROUP BY username
    ORDER BY SUM( token ) DESC
    LIMIT 10    
  ) t on t.username  =  user_tokens_list.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to list all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause, otherwise you would get errors (unless option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled); this is one reason why `select *` with `group by` is not a good practice.

```
select username, sum(token) total_tokens
from mytable
group by username
order by total_tokens desc
```

Note: mysql allows table aliases in the `order by` clause; this can make the query easier to understand when the expressions become more complex than just a `sum()`

Comment: @Barmar: I just added more context to my answer.

Comment: The first line is still confusing, since it implies that he's *not* using aggregation in his query.

Comment: @Barmar: ok. I put the important part of the answer on top.